# What is the best way to get notified of new payments received

Tags: bitcoind

Using the daemon and not a 3rd party pinging service, what is the best way to get notified of new payments?
Do we need to constantly poll the server?

Comment: AFAIK, there's no way in the standard client to add a callback. Seems like it would be a useful feature though.

Comment: Watch only addresses. On a mobile phone wallet.

Answer (score 4):

Bitcoin New transactions can be discovered by polling using the listsinceblock API command with the Bitcoin.org client.

Beginning with v0.8.2 of the Bitcoin-Qt/bitcoind client is -walletnotify option that can run a process when a transaction that affects the wallet is seen.

The BitsOfProof supernode will offer this as well I believe.

[Update: Thanks to [Pelle's answer](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/8133/153) to a related question,

You can do this using BitcoinJ by implementing the [PeerEventListener](http://code.google.com/p/bitcoinj/source/browse/core/src/main/java/com/google/bitcoin/core/PeerEventListener.java) interface.

The [OnTransaction](http://code.google.com/p/bitcoinj/source/browse/core/src/main/java/com/google/bitcoin/core/PeerEventListener.java#74) will be called every time a new Transaction is broadcast out and received from a Peer ]

Comment: Updated to refer to how -walletnotify will help with this.