# Is there any party who is archiving all transactions that have been broadcast?

Tags: transactions, blockchain.info, history

There is a person claiming that Blockchain.info/wallet [sent a transaction](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=164512.0) but for whatever reason that transaction never got included in a block.

If the transaction is valid today but perhaps just didn't get re-broadcast for whatever reason and has since expired from each node's memory pool, any party  with an archive of transactions could re-broadcast that transaction and it now might get included in a block.

Does anyone maintain an archive of all transactions, for instance, by archiving each [OnTransaction event in BitcoinJ](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/8133/153)?

Comment: The person who needed that transaction re-broadcast was able to resolve the issue so the rebroadcast isn't needed for that specific instance, but I'm still curious if there's an archive being kept anywhere of all transactions a particular node receives.

Answer (score -2):

Anybody that has downloaded the blockchain has a log of all transactions. Blockchain.info should have it. In the future only accept confirmed transactions

Comment: The blockchain has all the transactions included in the blockchain.  What the question is asking is all transactions that are broadcast to the peer, including invalid and unconfirmed ones.  Thanks though.